# Git : Failed at pushing to remote server, ' REPOSITORY_PATH ' is not a git command

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using Git with TortoiseGit on Windows XP,
and I have a remote bare repository on Windows Vista 64bit version.

When I tried to push my local files to remote bare repository, I got the following error message.

```
git.exe push    "origin" master:master

git: '/Git_Repository/.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

the arbitrary URL is : username@serverip:/Git_Repository/.git

The same arbitrary URL worked just fine while doing clone/fetch/pull.

Access from a local directory in remote machine to this bare repository has no problem either so I belive there is something wrong with my path.

I can push/pull at GitHub correctly but I was using URL provide by GitHub.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my configuration?

Here is my remote .git/config

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = true
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
```

Here is my local .git/config

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads
url = username@serverip:/Git_Repository/.git
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

I edited the URL to make it more precise，but it still show the same error

Even more, no matter what I type after the serverip, it still shows the same error message

if the URL is

> ssh://user@server ip/Git_Repositorywrongname/.git

then the error message

> git: '/Git_Repositorywrongname/.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

When user connects to the remote repository, the executed git commands are from bin directories in SSH. So I believe therer is wrong with my SSH configuration and this is why I can do git operations normally in local/ local in the remote machine.

I followed the guide in http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_CentralServerWindowsXP and linked the 4 commands

Did I miss anything?

Thanks for your reading

Comment: show .git/config -- you've got something quite strange in there, I imagine.

Comment: drop ".git" from the url

Comment: I am using cygwin to linux and have the same issue.  I created the remote repo as shared, and was able to clone it locally.  But now I can't push it back to the central server.   - even a basic "git push" from inside the repo kicks out the full "git: '/path/to/remote/repo.git/' is not a git command. See git --help."

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Run this command locally:

```
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
```

and then inside the local repo just run

```
git push origin master
```

Alternately you can append the recieveoack command to every push

```
git push --receive-pack='git receive-pack'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the protocol explicitly (here ssh), avoiding using the ':' between the user@host part, and the local path (look at the urls described in the [`git fetch` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)):

```
url = ssh://username@serverip/C:/Git_Repository/.git
```

In other words, avoid the [scp syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) for this kind of path.

Comment: I did tried the ssh url. But the result is the same.
git: '/Git_Repository/.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
And the correct usage for ssh url should be ssh://username@serverip/Git_Repository/.git if the directory is under C:/

Answer (score -1):

what about

```
git push file:///\\<machine-ip>/<share-remote-repo>/
```

Comment: fatal: '//<serverip>/Git_Repository/.git' does not appear to be a git repository.
It doesn't work...  :(
I think this url is for local directory, but still thanks

Comment: you need to have shared the remote repo, and try not to add the .git at the end of the path.

Comment: I tried to remove the .git from the end of path but it doesn't work